# java help on wrong if statements

Tags: java

well guys this is more of a java problem but i am trying to look what i did wrong with 3 different if statements .. 1st and 2nd has some bugs while 3rd works fine
well here how it can work

> /command arg arg
>
> /command arg arg playername
>
> /command arg arg -g
>
> /command arg arg  -g playername
>
> /command arg arg playername -g

so -g and playername can be on different sides

1st if statement

```
if (args.length == 3) {
    if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")) {
        glo = true;
    } else {
        if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[2]) != null) {
            k = args[2];
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[2] + " is not a player3");
        }
    }
}

if (args.length == 4) {
    if (args[3].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")) {
        glo = true;
    } else {
        if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[3]) != null) {
            k = args[3];
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[3] + " is not a player4");
        }
    }
}
```

whats wrong:

> /command arg arg wrongplayername -g

didnt noticed me with if the wrongplayername was wrong

and 2nd one

```
if (args.length > 2) {
    if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("-g") || ((args.length == 4) && (args[3].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")))) {
        glo = true;
    }
    if (args.length > 2) {
        if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[2]) != null) {
            k = args[2];
        } else if (args.length == 4 && Bukkit.getPlayer(args[3]) != null) {
            k = args[3];
        } else {
            if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[2]) == null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[2] + " is not a player1");
            } else if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[3]) == null) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[3] + " is not a player2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

whats wrong :

> /command arg arg -g

gives me the error -g is not a player name

and 3rd one which works fine

```
if (args.length == 3) {
    if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")) {
        glo = true;
    } else {
        if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[2]) != null) {
            k = args[2];
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[2] + " is not a player5");
        }
    }
} else if (args.length == 4) {
    if (args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")) {
        glo = true;
    } else {
        if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[2]) != null) {
            k = args[2];
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[2] + " is not a player6");
        }
    }
    if (args[3].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")) {
        glo = true;
    } else {
        if (Bukkit.getPlayer(args[3]) != null) {
            k = args[3];
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + args[3] + " is not a player7");
        }
    }
}
sender.sendMessage("2:" + " glo: " + glo + "  k: " + k);
```

i just want to spot what are the mistakes on 1st and 2nd 
and if there is a shorter / faster way to do this
 also here is the entire code with ctrl + f in eclipse http://hastebin.com/pivurukalu.coffee

Comment: Try to use Commons CLI: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/.

Comment: Your code is impossible to read with this indentation. Maybe if you indent it properly, you'll spot the problems yourself.

Comment: well i am not getting a command line input
im getting user input from chat

Comment: As @kruemel said, Commons CLI is easy to use, stable and solves this problem. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: On the first one, you say if(args[3].equalsIgnoreCase("-g")) then mark glo as true, OTHERWISE search for the player name. If the last option is -g with a length of 4, that means the playername must be at index 2, but because of your if it stops after just finding -g. http://pastebin.com/eLbywMfN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather re-write it to something that is easier to follow and maintain:

```
public static void parseCommand(String[] args) {

    String playerName = null;
    List<String> argsLst = Arrays.asList(args);              
    if (argsLst.contains("-g")) {
        argsLst.remove("-g");
        // do your logic for '-g' switch
        // ...
    }
    // now you have only two options:
    // /command arg arg
    // /command arg arg playername
    if (argsLst.size() == 3) {
        playerName = argsLst.remove(2);
    }

    // now we've got:
    // /command arg arg
    // so continue dealing with the two 'arg's
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice, this would also work if it was "-g arg arg" or "arg -g arg playername", or ...

Comment: @kruemel good point! with this implementation the order doesn't matter which is good & bad at the same time :) if the OP would want to "force" an order - it would make sense to allow only one single order and use an array with the implementation, or alternatively, to add some validations to this impl.

Comment: well since i have for loop i am illetrating through every arg
i dont have any order atm and it works if i add more args and/or names